# Can't push to branch with blacklisted pattern, even after i removed those file with new commit

Tags: git, gitlab

I am not able to push the changes into a branch with blacklisted pattern, even after i removed those file with new commit. Actually, I received the following error while pushing the changes into the remote branch.

```
remote: GitLab: File name domain/app-1.7.RELEASE.jar
was blacklisted by the pattern .+\.war|.+\.jar|.+\.exe|.+\.class|\.classpath|
\.project|\.settings|\.idea|.+\.iml|.+\.iws|\.flattened-pom.xml|target.

To gitlab.com:developerbhuwan/samplee.git
 ! [remote rejected]   ok-cx -> ok-cx (pre-receive hook declined)
```

How can solve this problem ?

Comment: But the commit containing the jar is still in the history, right? You're pushing *all* the commits. You need to rewrite the commit to remove the file that shouldn't be included, not add a second commit that takes it out again.

Comment: Rewrite commit, not add new commit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already created a new commit with that file deleted:

- get back to your old commit
- delete the file
- *amend* that old commit
- push back

That is:

```
git reset --hard @~
git rm wrong_file
git commit --amend "delete file"
git push
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Correct: a pre-receive hook indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Navigate to your project’s `Settings > Repository` and expand `Push Rules`.
Set the rule you want and click `Save Push Rules` for the changes to take effect

Comment: Following your steps and Unchecking 'Prevent pushing secret files' checkbox under Push Rules, solved my problem. Thanks.